# PDO::bindValue undefined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem with bind* functions in php

my code is :

```
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
$this->db_conn -> query ('SET NAMES utf8');
$this->db_conn -> query ('SET CHARACTER_SET utf8_unicode_ci');
$this->db_conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->db_conn -> prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `mail`) VALUES(:login,sha1(:password),:mail)');
$this->db_conn -> bindValue(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$this->db_conn -> bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$this->db_conn -> bindValue(':mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$this->db_conn -> execute();
```

error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()
```

Can anybody give me advice?

Comment: Well your error doesn't match your code, so either you don't show us the **real** code OR not the **real** error message

Comment: [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) returns a [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, *that* is what you call your bind and execute functions on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bindParam()` and `bindValue()` are methods of `PDOStatement` which is returned by the `prepare()` method. You need to store the return value of the call to `prepare()` and call `bindParam()` or `bindValue()` on that.

Try this:

```
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
$this->db_conn -> query ('SET NAMES utf8');
$this->db_conn -> query ('SET CHARACTER_SET utf8_unicode_ci');
$this->db_conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $this->db_conn -> prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `mail`) VALUES(:login,sha1(:password),:mail)');
$stmt -> bindValue(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindValue(':mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> execute();
```